# How change monitors from terminal ? "xrandr: Cant open display"

Tags: debian, xrandr, monitors, lxde, resolution

I'm booting [Sparkylinux](https://sparkylinux.org/) from a live-usb in a notebook with broken screen.

There is a external monitor connected by VGA.
The external monitor is booted dual with the notebook monitor And the external monitor resolution is booted with some issues.

To fix it i need to put the external monitor as the primary monitor, or even better, shutdown the notebook monitor. In Ubuntu i can use <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to change monitors.

In Lubuntu, even i cant see much, i can open the start menu, type `monitor` and change it manually.

In Sparkylinux the special key dosen't work and start menu is tricky, so i cant access the monitor menu whithout seeing.

So I'm trying `xrandr` to change it , but apearently i cant open the terminal ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), the bad resolution sends it to another realm.

So i used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to try `xrandr`, but for most but not all `xrandr` commands i get

```
"xrandr: Cant open display".
```

Like  `xrandr --listmonitors`

Answer (score 2):

`xrandr` is an Xwindows utility and expects to be run inside an X session, that's where the `Cant open display` comes from.

You could do this (if your DISPLAY is :0):

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ xrandr --listmonitors
$ xrandr your_command
```

Comment: For Bash, `DISPLAY:0` was not a valid identifier, but `export DISPLAY=:0` worked. See https://askubuntu.com/a/156037.

Comment: @Kyle, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: Can you please correct your typo in "xrand**r**" ?

Comment: @adamency typo fixed

Comment: @Eduardo thank you :)